# Black/White lines on screen when scrolling or watching video (browsing)

Tags: 14.04, graphics, nvidia-geforce

I have an ASUS k501U with Ubuntu 14.04 + Gnome 3.
Intel Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2) and NVIDIA GTX 950M.
In the details of sistem it shows that used Intel Graphics,
but don't understand why appears that lines.
Can someone help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

There is are lots of posts, including video describing your problem with skylake processors [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752743/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-6th-generation-screen-flickering). Some reasons are because kernel version are < 4.4.18. Others are because of Chrome smooth scrolling option. Others are because Xorg is using sna instead of uxa.

On my own system (Intel Core i7 3630QM w/HD3000 graphics + Nvidia GT650M) I had screen tearing in chrome that went away after updates and/or removing smooth scrolling option. However different processors (mine is third generation, yours is sixth generation) can use different machine code which can present different problems/features/benefits.

When you read the link above and wonder what kernel version you are using open the terminal and type:

```
uname -r
```

Changing Kernel versions is not like upgrading Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 where you can't quickly go back. You can have multiple kernel verions in your Grub boot screen (under advanced options submenu).

Please keep us updated in your progress because I'm sure others like me suffer similar, if not the same, problem.

Comment: Hi, @WinEunuuchs2Unix, thank you for answer:

uname -r:

WinEunuuchs2Unix

Comment: i'm still getting black lines when browsing or watching videos :(
can someone help-me, any previous solution doesn't work