# System Panel flickering

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, kde

My panel flickers randomly sometimes, I have tried everything. Can someone please help on how to fix it.
I am using nvidia graphics card
My PRIME profile is set to intel.

*Hardware Info:*

```
$ inxi -Fxz
System:    Host: neon Kernel: 4.8.0-36-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.9.2 (Qt 5.7.1) Distro: neon 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: HP (portable) product: HP Pavilion Notebook v: Type1ProductConfigId
           Mobo: HP model: 80A4 v: 91.1D Bios: Insyde v: F.79 date: 04/14/2016
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-6500U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 4096 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 10368
           clock speeds: max: 3100 MHz 1: 500 MHz 2: 499 MHz 3: 500 MHz 4: 499 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Sky Lake Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA GM108M [GeForce 940M] bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1920x1080@59.93hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.8.0-36-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
           driver: rtl8723be port: 4000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000 bus-ID: 04:00.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 500.1GB (92.9% used) ID-1: /dev/sda model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 500.1GB temp: 0C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 443G used: 418G (100%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 17.01GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 45.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 269 Uptime: 31 min Memory: 4297.3/15885.8MB Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (fish) inxi: 2.2.35
```

*Graphic Settings:*
[image]
*Nvidia Settings:*
[image]
*Drivers Installed:*

```
$ dpkg -l | grep nvidia
ii  nvidia-367                                      367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1+gpu16.04.1         amd64        NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57
ii  nvidia-opencl-icd-367                           367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1+gpu16.04.1         amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                    0.8.2                                      amd64        Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                                 378.09-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1                 amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
```

Comment: @Manoj Sawai no it doesn't.

Comment: @ManojSawai Tried 4.8. It still happens sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a common problem with Skylake HD graphics which you are using when Nvidia PRIME is set to "Intel". In this ([Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake 6th Generation Screen Flickering](https://askubuntu.com/questions/752743/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-6th-generation-screen-flickering)) Q&A the most voted answer is to:

Create or edit the file at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` as root with the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```

There are other suggestions in that Q&A but this is the best place to start. If that isn't enough there are other Q&A's here:

- [Intel Skylake Graphics Issues (Corruption/Flickering/Artifacts)](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=208299)
- [IntelHD 5500 Screen flickering](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=221746) one of the recommendations is to install the 4.9.2 kernel (now at 4.9.10) which you can do following these instructions: ([How do I update kernel to the latest mainline version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version/879920#879920))