# Are there any drivers I need to install to get power management to work on my HP Elitebook 820 G1 with Xubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, power-management, xfce, hp

I have a HP Elitebook 820 G1 laptop with Xubuntu 16.04 installed. Even though my power management settings in XFCE looks like this:

[image]

the monitor will go to sleep after X minutes and not wake up again.

Are there any special drivers I could look into to get this working?

Output from lspci:

```
Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
```

Kernel version:

```
$ uname -r
4.10.0-35-generic
```

Comment: Do you have hybrid graphics?

Comment: What is "hybrid graphics"?  You mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Hybrid_Graphics No, don't think so.

Comment: It seems a workaround for this problem is to set just not set the slider for "never", but instead set them for some value. As long as xfce is set to manage the power management and the sliders are set to anything but "Never" it seems to work for me :)

Answer (score 2):

You may be affected by [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302) which affected default 4.4.0 kernels in Xenial.

You can confirm your kernel version by issuing the command `uname -r` in the terminal. It has [been reported](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302/comments/42) and [confirmed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1566302/comments/43) that this issue is resolved with the [mainline kernel 4.4.11](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.4.11-xenial/) It's my understanding that the mainline kernels may not be supported here. Before plunging into the [reportedly unsupported](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version#comment1369815_879888) world of mainline kernels it's recommended that you [understand the implications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels) of doing so.

If you decide to install a mainline kernel regardless the process is outlined [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

A wiser and simpler approach might be to simply check the output of `apt-cache linux-image` for a newer kernel version than the one you are running (above 4.4.0) and install that package.

**EDIT:** If the above doesn't work for you, an alternative approach would be to obtain the latest [Intel Graphics Update Tool](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2) for your Ubuntu distribution and install that. Both 64-bit and 32-bit versions are available as of this moment.

Sources:

[How do I update kernel to the latest mainline version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879888/how-do-i-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version)

[How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)

[Should I upgrade to the "mainline" kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162616/should-i-upgrade-to-the-mainline-kernels)

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I run 4.10.0, see edit in question.

Comment: Updated answer.