# Use proprietary graphic drivers in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: nvidia, updates, 17.10

I have upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10 recently and am experiencing major graphics issues since. First, the system was booting to a black screen with some log file flickering up every few seconds (containing Apache status etc.). However, I could open a TTY by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 and after some research I found out that I had to uninstall the NVIDIA drivers which I had been working with for several years without problems.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

solved my problem, however I had to switch from Wayland to Xorg in addition to fix a laggy mouse and keyboard. 
Now, the system works fine, except for animations (like the app menu or scrolling in Google Chrome) being extremely laggy which I think is due to the missing NVIDIA drivier. I tried reinstalling the proprietary driver (384.90) in the "Additional Drivers" section in the update settings, which resulted in the same black screen error I mentioned above, so I had to uninstall the driver again.

Is there already a known fix to use the NVIDIA driver with Ubuntu 17.10 or any other way to make animations smooth again?

*EDIT* I tried uncommenting the line "WaylandEnable=false", as it was suggested to another person with a similar issue. Unfortunately, this did not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After the upgrade to 17.10 I only get a black screen. How do I fix this?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966666/after-the-upgrade-to-17-10-i-only-get-a-black-screen-how-do-i-fix-this)

Comment: Nvidia drive does not work with wayland yet but you can use it with X

Comment: I tried uncommenting the `# WaylandEnable=false` line, the problem persists.

Comment: I was able to get 17.10 working with nvidia-384 (no Wayland). I had the same black screen for my KDE setup. I noticed nvidia-384 had ignored errors during do-release-upgrade. The upgrade installed a lowlatency kernel but not the linux-headers that dkms+nvidia require. So install linux-headers-lowlatency if that's what you are running. To fix the dpkg error for nvidia-384 see comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969352/uninstalling-and-then-reinstalling-nvidia-384-kills-colord#comment1555568_969352)

Comment: install lightdm (replace gdm3) and install nvidia driver. GDM is causing black screen.

Comment: Related ? https://askubuntu.com/questions/971220/ubuntu-17-10-gnome-launcher-and-desktop-screen-issues