# Ubuntu 17.10 is using onboard intel as VGA adapter instead of nvidia card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.10, gpu-driver

After upgrading to 17.10 I noticed that my installation is using my onboard Intel graphics as VGA adapter instead of my Nvidia 940M.

I already installed the additional drivers from the software & updates, but this had no effect.

Output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer HD Graphics 530
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce 940M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: CLEVO/KAPOK Computer GM108M [GeForce 940M]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

And after running `gpu-manager`

```
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
can't access /run/u-d-c-fglrx-was-loaded file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
/etc/modprobe.d is not a file
Looking for fglrx modules in /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Error: can't open /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-lowlatency/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? no
Is fglrx loaded? no
Was fglrx unloaded? no
Is fglrx blacklisted? no
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is fglrx kernel module available? no
Is nvidia kernel module available? no
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:191b
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:1347
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver. Skipping...
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-eDP-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 1
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? no
How many cards? 1
Has the system changed? No
main_arch_path x86_64-linux-gnu, other_arch_path i386-linux-gnu
update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for x86_64-linux-gnu_gfxcore_conf
Current alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
Current core alternative: (null)
Current egl alternative: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa-egl/ld.so.conf
Is nvidia enabled? no
Is nvidia egl enabled? no
Is fglrx enabled? no
Is mesa enabled? yes
Is mesa egl enabled? yes
Is pxpress enabled? no
Is prime enabled? no
Is prime egl enabled? no
Is nvidia available? yes
Is nvidia egl available? no
Is fglrx available? no
Is fglrx-core available? no
Is mesa available? yes
Is mesa egl available? yes
Is pxpress available? no
Is prime available? yes
Is prime egl available? no
Single card detected
Nothing to do
No change - nothing to do
```

How can I set my Nvidia card to be my main display adapter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you are on a laptop with a single video output... Have you checked the BIOS settings for 'Integrated Video'? If the setting is "Always Enabled",  the nVidia graphics will not be switchable because the integrated graphics are always ON . If you set it to something like 'Always use discrete' or 'Disabled', the system should always use the discrete adapter (nVidia). Using automatic switching is tricky as I have noticed one adapter is active when I "think" the other should be on. Sometimes when I turn off secure boot to install Linux, I notice this can also change. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Orian I just checked my BIOS settings but unfortunately, I don't have the integrated video setting. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I had a similar issue after upgrading to 17.10. I noticed that the nvidia-384 install had errors. For you make sure you have dkms installed + linux-headers-lowlatency (since you are using the lowlatency kernel) 

To fix the dpkg error when installing nvidia-384 see comment here:[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969352/uninstalling-and-then-reinstalling-nvidia-384-kills-colord#comment1555568_969352)