# Screen flickering since Ubuntu install

Tags: drivers, hdmi, intel, i915

I have a screen flickering since my first Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS installation and tried everything mentioned in this post: [Flickering screen with Intel graphics on Ubuntu 17.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927407/flickering-screen-with-intel-graphics-on-ubuntu-17-04?newreg=7745ee34ca994d36beb5806b8cd8e09b)
and setting it to `nomodeset` helps. My problem is that if i set it to `nomodeset` my second screen, connected via HDMI isn't recognized.

If i don't set `nomodeset`, HDMI is recognized and it does not flicker on the HDMI screen, just on my laptop screen.

I would love to use both screens!

this is my `lshw -C video`

```
   *-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller

   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
   resources: irq:127 memory:b0000000-b0ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: 4.4.0-127-generic #153-Ubuntu

Comment: Start with upgrading the kernel by `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04` and reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your video adapter is probably poorly supported by the old 4.4 kernel.

You can upgrade the kernel in Ubuntu 16.04 to a newer major version by running

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-16.04
```