# Why is my laptop screen flickering uncontrollably on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: laptop, screen, monitor, acer, flicker

This issue is best illustrated visually, hence I created a recording in the form of an GIF of my laptop screen flickering hectically. The flickering doesn't seem to have a pattern associated with it - it comes and goes on a whim.

[image]

It's also important to note that the issue appeared first after the upgrade from 19.04 to 19.10. That's why I decided to refrain from using Eoan in hopes of the issue not being present anymore in future releases like Focal.

The flickering may be barely noticeable but more often than not it is quite intense, hence I find it to be a major issue. After suspending the computer and re-logging the issue disappears for circa 30 seconds.

The following [issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044246/screen-flickering-since-ubuntu-install) may be related.

Edit: Here are the hardware specs and most importantly the [Display and Graphics](https://gist.github.com/mateja176/b9820655749e18de25956296ca47d1fe#display--graphics)

Comment: Was it, or has anyone report the issue (ie. via bug report).  Developers won't be aware of the issue until reported (where details of the video hardware in use will be necessary)

Comment: I've added the hardware details, thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: Those look like specs from a brochure, detailed specs as seen by the kernel are more useful (`lshw`, `lspci` etc), eg. if helpful see https://askubuntu.com/questions/72766/how-do-i-find-out-the-model-of-my-graphics-card

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I found out that ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS has 5.8 kernel which caused this apparently. I then revert back to 20.04.1 LTS which has 5.4 kernel. The issue disappeared. Check your installed kernel version. If its 5.8 then go back to 5.4