# Arandr: blinking monitor issue

Tags: multiple-monitors

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 and Arandr 0.1.9 and sometimes my external display would start blinking on and off in rapid succession, making it unusable. This didn't happen on the Windows computers at 2 different repair shops, at least not within the 3 minute tests.

I bought a new monitor thinking the other one was defective. The new one did the same thing. I tried restarting and found this cleared the issue temporarily.

Based on the system restart working, as well as windows, I believe this to be a software issue. Anyone know what might cause a blinking screen like this?

I have a Lenovo G767 laptop with i7-3612QM processor and integrated intel HD4000 graphics.

```
owner@G700:~$ sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for owner: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:27 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Can you please provide some details as to video module (driver) in use, eg. `sudo lshw -C video` to list-hardware of class video

Comment: @guiverc , thank you for that command, I have run it and updated the top post.

Comment: I've not had any ideas for this sorry, the only issue I've had was on a box when it upgraded to 19.10 (or 5.3 kernel) but it was nvidia & I didn't explore as 19.10 isn't supported for that architecture. Are you using the original 18.04 software stack? or HWE stack? (ie. 5.3 now too).  The obvious is check cables (try a different cable), or intel suggest looking for interference (https://www.intel.com.au/content/www/au/en/support/articles/000026580/graphics-drivers/graphics-for-7th-generation-intel-processors.html).

Comment: Some items in  Some things from other posts like https://askubuntu.com/questions/752743/ubuntu-16-04-skylake-6th-generation-screen-flickering maybe worth trying, but if they didn't work I'd back out the changes (e.g I'd try tear 1 up-vote tear free suggestion myself but it's a blind-luck feeling that makes we wonder if it'd work)

Comment: @guiverc it appears to be related to my HDMI cable. I'm plugged in through VGA and it works without issues now :)

Comment: sounds like cable; so replace it.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary workaround I have switched to using a VGA cable for my connection and the problem is resolved.