# Screen flickering on certain apps in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: graphics, screen, monitor, flicker

I use Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS on a dual-monitor setup. These are the relevant components of my PC:

**CPU:** AMD Ryzen 7 3700X 3.6GHz

**Motherboard:** Asus TUF GAMING X570-PLUS

**Memory:** Corsair Vengeance LPX 16GB (2 x 8GB) DDR4-3200

**Storage:** Samsung 850 EVO-Series 500GB 2.5" SSD

**Storage:** Crucial P1 1 TB M.2-2280 NVME SSD

**Video Card:** Gigabyte Radeon RX 5700 XT 8GB
**Power Supply:** SeaSonic EVO 620W
**Monitor:** AOC G2460PF 24.0"    1920x1080 144Hz
**Monitor:** AOC 23.6" WIDESCREEN - 1920 x 1080 60Hz

I am experiencing screen flicking in the top left hand side of certain apps, such as Chrome and Slack, particularly when moving my mouse or using the keyboard. This is always in the top left hand corner of the app, but otherwise is quite inconsistent. It seems to happen more on the cheaper 23.6" AOC monitor, but that could be a red herring as it does happen on both. I've uploaded a brief video of this happening to show you what I mean [here](https://streamable.com/tq4yps). I have a separate Windows partition where I don't experience this issue, so I am convinced that it is not a hardware issue, but something to do with Ubuntu.

After some searching online I can see quite a few people have had similar issues with various versions of Ubuntu, but nothing that was exactly this. I am new to Ubuntu and am cautious about typing things into the terminal that I don't really understand and that might not be relevant to what I'm seeing here, so am keen to get some advice that is bespoke to my issue before troubleshooting any further. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 16.04 Skylake 6th Generation Screen Flickering](https://askubuntu.com/q/752743/)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else looking, I managed to solve this by updating my kernel - [this is a good article on how to do so easily](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu).

Note that for the problem to be solved you'll need to restart afterwards to boot into the new kernel.

Comment: Which kernel was problematic, and which one solved the issue?